# How do I do a complicated initialization of a Variable in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a Variable that will be the weights for a CNN. Let's say it is of shape [kernel_width, kernel_height, in_channels, out_channels].

What I want to do is to initialize it with some random values, but with the central value of each kernel to be 1.

For example, for a 3x3 kernel, I want the values to be [[r,r,r],[r,1,r],[r,r,r]], where each r is a different random value taken from whatever distribution.

I can easily create a numpy array in that format, but I couldn't see how I could use an arbitrary array to initialize a Variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the easiest way to go is to initialize the filter with a numpy array. You just have to pass this array at the creation of the Variable:

```py
filter_value = 0.1 * np.random.randn(3, 3, 64, 64)
filter_value[1, 1, :, :] = 1.  # set the center value to 1.

filter = tf.Variable(filter_value, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/variables/index.html seems to imply that only tensors can be used to initialize variables.

Comment: Anything that can be transformed to a tensor is valid according to the doc, which means a list is ok, a numpy array is ok.

Comment: Thanks -- can you point me to where the doc says that, please?

Comment: Init method of [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable)

Comment: I can see why I missed seeing that single clause. Thanks again.

Comment: The above code doesn't quite work. It's necessary to write filter = tf.Variable(filter_value, dtype=tf.float32) .